# How to connect mssql with php 7.2.5

Tags: sql-server-2008, php-7.2, ubuntu-18.04

I've worked with a system on Ubuntu server 17. But after I've upgraded to 18.04 LTS, my mssql connection stopped working.

This is my following program line:

```
$serverName = "IP OF MY SERVER";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "DB NAME",
    "Uid" => "USER",
    "PWD" => "PASSWORD"
);
//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
//Select Query
$tsql = "SELECT @@Version as SQL_VERSION";
//Executes the query
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
//Error handling

if ($getResults == FALSE)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);

function FormatErrors($errors) {
    /* Display errors. */
    echo "Errors: <br/>";

    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: " . $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Code: " . $error['code'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Message: " . $error['message'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

The current version of my php is 7.2.5.
What should I do considering that everything is updated?

Answer (score 0):

In the last version I hadn't to manually install the ssql driver.
But in the newest version of Ubuntu it's necessary.

After installed by following these procedures [PROCEDURES](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/) it has working again.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect this way.
Syntax

```
 connection mysql_connect(server,user,passwd,new_link,client_flag);
```

EX

```
<?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
     $dbuser = 'guest';
     $dbpass = 'guest123';
     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
     if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     echo 'Connected successfully';
     mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't it work only with MySQL? Because I'm using Microsoft SQL.